# How to validate all constrains that do not have any group?

Tags: spring, validation, bean-validation

Thanks to the [validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation I can execute selective constraints in a controller. I would like to check all validations that do not have any group.

Let's say I have a complex object like:

```
@NotNull(groups = ValidateAfterGroup.class)
@getter @setter
private String field1;

@NotNull
@getter @setter
private String field2;

@NotNull
@getter @setter
private String field3;

@NotNull
@getter @setter
private String field4;

@NotNull
@getter @setter
private String field5;

@Valid
@getter @setter
private List<Component> myComponent;
```

I want to validate the constraints in field2, field3,... field5 and those that may be contained in Component without annotation. If I use this in the controller without any group I do not see any constraint validated.

```
public String save(Model model, @ModelAttribute @Validated Form myForm, BindingResult result){
```

I could add a grupo to the @Validated annotation but I would have to add it to all constraints. I have lots of object. Can I avoid to add the groups?

Comment: All constraints belong to a group, explicitly or implicitly. If there is no explicit group defined a constraint belong to the `javax.validation.groups.Default` group. You could explicitly request the validation of the Default group in your scenario, but not specifying any group should automatically validate the default group. My guess is there might be something else wrong in your setup, but it is hard to without any further information.

Comment: Can I do @Validated(javax.validation.groups.Default) ?

Comment: You should be. However, I would also expect it to work w/o, since not specifying any group should automatically validate the Default group.